# Finding a permutation to satisfy given condition

Tags: abstract-algebra

In $S_n$ with n=10, find a permutation $a$ such that $axa^{-1} = y$ if $x=(1,2)(3,4)$ and $y=(5,6)(3,1)$

I don't know how to start doing this. I read something like I need to get, for this case, $$(a(1),a(2)) \qquad \mbox{ and} \qquad (a(3),a(4))$$ but I am not sure where will I get their equivalents. Also, will those be my permutation $a$? Please help. I have problems very similar to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we need a permutation $a$ such that $axa^{-1}=a(1,2)a^{-1}\cdot a(3,4)a^{-1}$ equals to $(5,6)(3,1)$. this can be done if : $a(1,2)a^{-1}=(a(1),a(2))=(5,6) $ and $a(3,4)a^{-1}=(a(3),a(4))=(3,1) $ so I think that you can continue from here , not that the remaining integers can be fixed or just complete the permutation